# How to reverse 2d list in python?

Tags: python, list, 2d

This is my 2d list:

```
numbers = [(1,2,3,4,5),(6,7,8,9,10),(11,12,13,14,15)]
```

What I want to get is this:

```
numbers = [(15,14,13,12,11),(10,9,8,7,6),(5,4,3,2,1)]
```

The only method I know is this:

`for i in numbers[::-1]:
    print(i)`

Can anyone help?

Comment: you want to just reverse or get the result in reverse(descending) order?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
print([i[::-1] for i in numbers[::-1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

## generic reverse function

```
def reverse2DList(inputList):

    #reverese items inside list
    inputList.reverse()
   
    #reverse each item inside the list using map function(Better than doing loops...)
    inputList = list(map(lambda x: x[::-1], inputList))
    
    #return
    return inputList
```

Comment: My2Cents: _Better than doing loops_ not really, should be the same performance.
Don't use too many comment _#return return inputlist_ ... That's not very useful. You could return immediately without turning the map into a list. In that case the caller can do whatever he wants with out (more useful imho). But apart from that, it's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`reversed`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/) function

```
numbers = [(1,2,3,4,5),(6,7,8,9,10),(11,12,13,14,15)]

for sublist in reversed(numbers):
    print list(reversed(sublist))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another way

```
print map(lambda x: list(reversed(x)),reversed(numbers))
```

Comment: you have to reverse the list also

Comment: oh.. Thanks @SmartManoj